Suprima Sensor Active only while OTG mode and Fingerprint Reader on from Developer Option
On my BH502 Android Device I am using the SDK for Fingerprint Template Register. But my only concern is that when I am enable USB in OTG mode and Power on Finger Reader mode then only Surprema sensor light is on. And after that I am able to use all commands of the SDK. May I know how to use without enable both options manually from developer option? And if not then how to enable programmatically via Android code we can enable both options? Please help me on this as it is a big concern for us.
I tried different code in android how to enable both the modes but it is not working. And I am using this project Suprema

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I attached a link of GitHub project which SDK I am using for fingerprint enrollment ,Identify And Verify commands  in my Android application. So it is not about code, I asked that is it possible to Enable OTG mode and Fingerprint reader mode from developer option via Android programming code?
